# Words of Chinese origin in English?

Tags: etymology

When it comes to word-loaning, English sure stands out. Having come across many loan words from other languages, I started to wonder if China too blames us of contemporary word-theft. Well, apart from the [obvious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Chinese_origin) such as `Kung-fu`, `Ih-don-kno` or `tea`. I am on the look out for some strong words along the lines of [Zeitgeist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitgeist) or [Ménage à trois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_%C3%A0_trois), something mainstream, something modern yet Chinese.

[Tuhao seems to have caught up](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-24677113).

Comment: “Ih-don-kno” is obvious?!?

Comment: So are you asking for _more_ than what is in the wiki article?

Comment: @Mitch [Wiki ain't the final say.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:General_disclaimer)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What was that word in English for hidden humor?

Comment: BottledBrick, you should edit your question then to clarify, say explicitly "I'd like _more_ words than are already in the wiki article." Also, explain the "Ih don kno" example or remove.

Answer (score 4):

[kowtow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kowtow) (叩头)  = to prostrate oneself before another.

[Junk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junk_%28ship%29) - which is somehow taken from a variant pronunciation for 船.

Comment: Have heard of Pow wow but Kowtow is new. Sounds tacky though.

Comment: Bravo on being [Junk](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=junk&defid=2038820) specific!

Comment: I’m quite wary of that etymology of ‘junk’. It is clearly from Malay/Javanese (and I trust that form is _djong_, since it’s also given by the OED and etymonline), but there seems to be nothing to indicate that _djong_ is related to 船. OED says: “Some have sought the origin of the word in the Chinese ch'wan ‘ship or sailing vessel’; but the Portuguese and Dutch were established in Java and the Malay Archipelago before they visited China, and found the Javanese and Malay word (which has no connection with the Chinese) applied to all large local vessels as well as [cont’d]

Comment: to the Chinese ships which visited those shores.” 船 is reconstructed by Karlgren as *ɗ’i̯wan, and by Akiyasu Tōdō as *diuə̆n, neither of which has even the vaguest hint of a velar final (Japanese onyomi is also _sen_, which is entirely incompatible with the [dzuːŋ] claimed on Wikipedia).